# Regex Matches any new line within a comment

Tags: regex, comments, notepad++

Is there a way to search for any  `\n` within a comment `""` in Notepad++ and replace it so that there are no spaces within the comments?

For example:

```
This is just an example

"Hello, 

I am separated. 

But I would like 

to be [together]"

Finish
```

I can change the first `"` for a `<` and the second `"` for a `>` but within `<>` or `""` should not be any space:

I would like to have the following result:

```
This is just an example

"Hello, I am separated. But I would like to be [together]"

Finish
```

Thanks,

Comment: from notepadd++ you can do it, but not with just one replace command, you will have to repeatedly press replace command unless all the \n is removed, will that do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- Find what: `[^"]*(?:\G|")\K([^"\r\n]+)\R+`
- Replace with: `$1`

Where:

- `(?:\G|")` : end of the previous successful match or double quote
- `\K`       : reset operator that discards the previous match
- `[^"\r\n]+`: 1 or more character that is not `"`, `\r` or `\n`
- `\R+`      : 1 or more line break

Comment: Thanks Toto, but this will work if the cursor is within a comment. For example: The cursor is represented by `x`. If the cursor is outside the comment as `x("...")` it won't find anything. But if the cursor is within the comment `"x"` it will find it. Is there a way to start looking outside the comment as  `x""` and finding the next `""`?

Comment: @Chüngel: Just add `[^"]*` at the begining of the regex. See my edit.

Comment: Still not working. Please see the example: [link](https://regex101.com/r/Ha70iw/1) I can change the first `"` for a `<` and the second `"` for a `>` but I would like to remove the blank spaces in the lines that contain comments.